# Im getting this error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object

Tags: java, json, gson

***I need to take the "id" from "weather" part, that come from json file.***

I know that i have to take the first element but I don't know how to do it. How i get first element using get method?

A part weatherMap all code works fine! Try it out and let me know what's the problem

**Java file**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.net.*;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.*;
public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String str) {
  Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(
    str, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
  );
  return map;
}


StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  result.append(line);
}
rd.close();

Map<String, Object> weatherMap = jsonToMap(respMap.get("weather")[0].toString());
System.out.println("ID logo: " + weatherMap.get("icon"));
```

**Json file**

```json
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 12.84,
    "lat": 45.78
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d" // I need this
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 16.67,
    "feels_like": 16.35,
    "temp_min": 16.11,
    "temp_max": 17.22,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "humidity": 64
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.45,
    "deg": 230,
    "gust": 1.34
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1603033884,
  "sys": {
    "type": 3,
    "id": 2003804,
    "country": "IT",
    "sunrise": 1602998965,
    "sunset": 1603037863
  },
  "timezone": 7200,
  "id": 3170086,
  "name": "Portogruaro",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: What is `respMap`?

Comment: You need to tell us everything we need to know to solve your problem.  We can't guess.   Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance.

Comment: To follow up on @RobertHarvey's post, what is `jsonToMap`?  Is that a custom method or a library method?  If it's a custom one, what is its implementation?  If it's a library one, from what library?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't compile, which makes it very difficult for anybody to help you.  Of particular note, `respMap` is used but never defined.  Since this the critical section of the code that's erroring out, you're unlikely to be able to get any useful help until you fix it.  To get the best assistance, you should make sure the code you provide compiles and runs on its own, and gives the error you want help with when run.

Comment: You need `id` as you said in the first line on post, but you need value of field `icon` as you marked in JSON file. Which do you really want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve the field icon